# Teradata: Get quarter for specific date

Tags: teradata

When selecting the maximum date of a column how do I obtain which quarter that date falls into without using a `CASE` statement?

Comment: What is a "quarter number"?

Comment: Do you mean to find if the date is in 1st, 2nd, 3rd or 4th quarter of a year?

Comment: Then perhaps `(2 + EXTRACT(MONTH FROM MAX(date_column))) / 3`

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: You can create a reference table (Month, Quarter) and you can extract month from your date column and join with it. (Joining this table won't affect performance as PI will be month)

```
Mth| Quarter
1  | 1
2  | 1
3  | 1
4  | 2
5  | 2
6  | 2
7  | 3 
8  | 3
9  | 3
10 | 4
11 | 4
12 | 4
```

Option 2: Use a logic as `(2+Month)/3` as in

```
SELECT FLOOR((2+EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE_CLM))/3)
```

Comment: No `FLOOR` needed as it's an integer division, see ypercubeᵀᴹ's comment.

Comment: Yeah but to be safer side, and to make it more generalize i have mentioned floor. Because in Postgresql the same query was giving fractional values. You can cross check.

Comment: You could also use a short `TO_CHAR(DATE_CLM, 'Q')` in both Teradata and PostgreSQL, but this returns a string instead of an INT.

Comment: Yes. There are many ways!